# Proof of correctness of reversal algorithm for array rotation

Tags: algorithms, arrays

We are given an array A of size n and we have to rotate it in left direction by d positions. So e.g. if `A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` then for `d = 2`, the resultant rotated array is `{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2}`.

One algorithm which does this goes as follows:

1. Reverse `A[0..d-1]` (0-indexing)
2. Reverse `A[d..n-1]`
3. Reverse `A[0..n-1]`

These three steps surprisingly rotate the array correctly. What is the math behind this algorithm? Why does it give a correct solution? It feels magical to me. I am not able to put up a formal proof of its correctness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof by picture, which follows the steps of the algorithm:
$$
0,\ldots,d-1,d,\ldots,n-1 \\
d-1,\ldots,0,d,\ldots,n-1 \\
d-1,\ldots,0,n-1,\ldots,d \\
d,\ldots,n-1,0,\ldots,d-1
$$
You can easily turn this into a formal proof by giving a formula for the permutation after each step, which you can easily prove correct.

Comment: This is a good starting point but not sure how to give formula for the permutation?

Comment: Take it as an exercise. Your formula could involve two separate cases.

Answer (score 1):

First, we can see the rotation problem (as described in the question) as equivalent to: interchange of two blocks of elements which are at index-ranges $[0, d-1]$ and $[d, n-1]$. Let's call these blocks, with elements exactly as the original array $A$, as $B_1$ and $B_2$. As result of this interchange, the order of these blocks in $A$ should change from $(B_1,B_2)$ to $(B_2,B_1)$.

In the provided algorithm, after the first two steps, array $A$ would contain:

$B_1$(reversed), followed by, $B_2$(reversed).

Now, if this modified array $A$ is read/iterated from end to start, it should return elements in order:

$[B_2$(reversed)(reversed) $\leftrightarrow B_2]$, followed by, $[B_1$(reversed)(reversed) $\leftrightarrow B_1]$.

which is the intended order. The third step modifies $A$ to reflect such order, by reversing.